# Classic Blender keymap mouse behavior -> Industry Compatible keymap [Change MMB to LMB]

Tags: interface

I'm new to Blender, came from Maya LT. I'm very happy with what industry keymap 2.8 has to offer, just wanted to ask if it's possible (I tried and "bricked" my controls several times, had to delete config folder from appdata folder to restore defaults) to have mouse behavior from Blender classic keymap?

For example, when I use move tool, gizmo appears, so now I need to press MMB to move something and it confirms when I release MMB button. In classic keymap I press G (or whatever keybind for a move/grab tool) and the component or object initially "sticks" to my mouse so I can move it where I want and press LMB to confirm my transformation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually edit the way the view port works by going to

```
Edit > Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > 3D View (Global) > Rotate View
```

Click the box in the third column and hit the preferred mouse interaction, e.g. just middle mouse button.

For me the biggest annoyance was that I wasn't able to rotate my view (orbit) using Alt + middle mouse button, because of some obscure settings in my OS (Linux Mint / Ubuntu). Therefore I didn't need to change all mouse interaction settings and could just selectively choose some view port interactions to change manually; perhaps the same holds for you. Hope this helps.